# How to execute the rest of the php script after json_encode output?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have a simple form with four input fields, name, email, phone, and message.  I am using JavaScript with Ajax to post my input fields to a PHP file for validations and mailing via phpmailer.

I collect the errors in an array from the validation functions. The I use and if statement to send the errors back to the html page via `json_encode(array)` function and exit the script. Else, I let the script to continue to and successfully send the email to my inbox.

The problem I have is `json_encode(array)` exit the script where errors were found or not. Even if I do not forcefully exit the script with die or exit. In that respect, no email is sent as the script is prematurely terminated.
I listed below a few lines from my php file to show how my if statement is set up.

I have searched the web for answers to no avail. I tried to place the `json_encode` function as different location in the file, and it did not work. I tried combining the error array with the success or failure strings from the mail sent function and did not work.

```
if ( $errors != null ) {
    echo json_encode( $errors );
    exit;
} else {  

 $mail = new PHPMailer( true );

    /* Set the mail sender. */
    $mail->setFrom( 'jsmith@gmail.com', 'John Smith' );

    /* Add a recipient. */
    //set who is receving mail
    $mail->addAddress( 'heh@hotmail.com' );

    /* Set the subject. */
    $mail->Subject = 'New message from contact form';

    /* Set email to be sent as HTML */
    $mail->isHTML( true );

    /* Set the mail message body. */
    $mail->Body =
```

I am expecting that once the if statement clears the errors, the entire php file script will continue until the data is emailed. However that is not happening.

Comment: So you want to send email even if any validation error occurs?

Comment: If there is no error, assume that will make `$errors = null`, there is no way that `json_encode()` will run. I think you need to check the value of `$errors`.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear (and confusing). Why would you want to send the email on errors? Isn't that the form validation errors? Also, we have _no idea_ how you define the `$errors` variable or what it contains in which situation. Please clarify what you actually want and show us more of your code (like what actually happens before this).

Comment: Use var_dump to find out what $errors actually contains in this case.

Comment: I am not sending the email on errors. I captures the validation errors in an array first. Then use an "if" statement to send the values of the errors array back to the html page and exit the script. If no errors I let the script to continue to run until the email is sent. However, once I use the echo JSON_Encode function to send the status, the script will terminate whether there was errors or not.

Comment: Here is the results I get when I do not have any validation errors:Result: [null,null,null,null,null,null,null] contactForm.htm:323:13
json parsed: ,,,,,,

Comment: And, here is the message I get when I use print_r($errors):Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => ). And, here is the message I get when I use var_dumb($errors): array(7) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL [4]=> NULL [5]=> NULL [6]=> NULL }

Comment: Instead of this `if ( $errors != null )` try this ->  `if (!empty($errors))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from another related question I posted on a different post. The errors array was containing all null variables that the conditional statement I had to determine whether the mail should be sent on Boolean false (no errors found) was not considering the array as empty. I had to change the conditional if statement to use array_filters instead.